# how to find id of product on click of autosuggestion using elastic search in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

i am using elasticsearch with my rails application(railscasts #306,#307) now i want to know how i can get id of a product on click of any autosuggestion, so that i can find that product and can show user only that perticular product record. i am using tire gem and my model query is as follow:

```
include Tire::Model::Search
include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  settings index: { 
    number_of_shards: 1, 
    number_of_replicas: 0,
  } do
    mapping do
      indexes :name, :type => 'string'
    end
  end

 def self.search(params)
    if params[:query].present?
      tire.search(load: true) do
        query { string "#{params[:query]}*"}
      end      
    else
      tire.search(load: true) do
        query { string "*#{params["term"]}*"}
      end
    end 
  end
```

Please help me as soon as possible and thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to add id to your mapping? `indexes :id, :index => :not_analyzed`.

Comment: i don't want to search based on id. on my controller i am using  render json: titles, here titles is an array of product name. now please tell me how i should render my object so that on click of auto complete i can get the product id.

Comment: Instead of rendering array of product names, you will render array of objects({ id, name })

Comment: thanks for your response but now can you please tell me how i can get the id on click using jquery. i have bind click event on .ui-menu-item of auto complete ui.

Comment: Ok, if you added `indexes :id` into your mapping, when you perform `Product.search({ 'term' => 'your term' })` you will get array of hashes: `[{id: 1, name: 'prduct name'}]`. And you should render this array to your front-end.

Comment: its working fine but i am not able to get id of product on click. i would be very thank full to you if you tell me how i can get product id on click event.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123424/discussion-between-sergei-stralenia-and-awsm-sid).